# Cropping tile map into raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, clip, gdalwarp, mbtiles

I want to create a layer background for my data map.
I am using a WMTS layer or a mbtile file (layer B), it could be an OpenStreetMap.

My plan is to merge this layer with a data layout which has holes (layer D).

I looking to extract a raster of layer B and crop it to the size of layer D.

In QGIS, I am using the command ***Raster>Extract> Cut with layer mask***

No matter the options I tried , I get an error message like:

> ERROR 4:
> crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=mbtiles&url=file:///home/me/Cartes_GIS/layerB_qgis_z6-11_v1.mbtiles:
> No such file or directory

the gdal command created by QGIS is

> gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -of GTiff -tr 1.0 -1.0 -tap
> -cutline /home/me/Cartes_GIS/gabarits.gpkg -cl mymask_CRS3857 -crop_to_cutline -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=75 "crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=mbtiles&url=file:/home/me/Cartes_GIS/layerB_qgis_z6-11_v1.mbtiles"
> /tmp/test_cut.tif

I am using QGIS 3.16.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: The path to the MBTiles file does not look correct, try to switch it out with "/home/me/Cartes_GIS/layerB_qgis_z6-11_v1.mbtiles" and then run the enitre gdalwarp command in OSGeo shell instead.

Comment: Addition: I get the same error as you using QGIS 3.24. There seems to be a bug where QGIS creates the path to MBTiles files in a way that the GDAL tools does not understand. In my experience, just using the straightforward path to the file should work in the GDAL tools.